# Hiding NavigationBar before and after segue

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios5, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I have an application where a TableView Controller segues to a ViewController and then to another.

I want to maximize real estate in the TVC and use

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
```

to hide the bar.  However, the bar returns to the view on the return from segue.

The app was constructed in storyboard for 5.1 using Xcode 4.3.1.

Can anyone assist by telling me where I can place a similar instruction to remove the Navbar on return from segue OR suggest an alternative method.

I have exhausted all means in storyboard by changing attributes for the controllers involved.  However what you see in Storyboard isn't always what I get.

Comment: Solved my problem by adding-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:NO];

}

Comment: Thank you John Jamieson, it's working, but `viewWillAppear:` and method `setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES` is a little bit better. Try it.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer above in the comment so just documenting it because I used it and it worked well! Thanks to @Tomasz.

To prevent the navigation bar reappearing in the header once you go back with the segue, use the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Just a couple of notes to improve the answer: 1. Don't forget to call super's implementation & 2. You could just pass `animated` instead of `YES` to maintain visual coherence

Answer (score 1):

### Swift solution

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

Thanks @spacemonkey and @Tomasz, this worked.